# All possible POWERBALL numbers

Tags: c++

The code does needs to not repeat Powerball numbers in one console line or in text file. I think its somewhere in the if statements. The first five numbers would be the white balls the ending number in the output lines is after the tab.
1 2 3 59 59 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    ofstream out_stream;
    out_stream.open("powerball.txt"); // text file
    for (int i = 1; i <= 59; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 59; j++) // loop and if statements for powerball repeat check
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                j = i + 1;
            }
            if (j == 60)
            {
                j = j - 1;
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= 59; k++) // loop and if statements with powerball repeat check
            {
                if (k == i)
                {
                    k = k + 1;
                    if (k == j)
                    {
                        k = k + 1;
                    }
                }
                if (k == 60)
                {
                    k = k - 1;
                }
                for (int l = 1; l <= 59; l++) // loop and if statements with powerball repeat check
                {
                    if (l == i)
                    {
                        l = l + 1;
                        if (l == j)
                        {
                            l = l + 1;
                            if (l == k)
                            {
                                l = l + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (l == 60)
                    {
                        l = l - 1;
                    }
                    for (int m = 1; m <= 59; m++) // loop and if statements for powerball repeat check
                    {
                            if (m == i)
                            {
                                m = m + 1;
                                if (m == j)
                                {
                                    m = m + 1;
                                    if (m == k)
                                    {
                                        m = m + 1;
                                        if (m == l)
                                        {
                                            m = m + 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        if (m == 60)
                        {
                            m = m - 1;
                        }
                        for (int n = 1; n <= 35; n++) // red ball and output count
                            {
                                out_stream << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << " " << m << "\t" << n << "\n";
                                cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << " " << m << "\t" << n << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use all random numbers - the chances of getting a repeated number sequence are the same as the chances of winning the jackpot, vanishingly small.

Comment: @Mark: He's worried about repeated numbers within a sequence, not entire sequence repeated.  Also, birthday problem says the chances of a repeated sequence aren't so small, since you have N-choose-2 pairs.

Comment: @J.p.: Your "fix" of adding 1 any time the RNG picks a repeat is broken.  First, it tremendously increases the chance of getting adjacent numbers.  Secondly, you aren't fixing repeat `59`, since you add one creating `60` (illegal) and then subtract one, making double `59` again.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. The button is labelled `Ask Question` for a reason.

Comment: Thanks i'll do some more research. is there another way to do it than nested loops?

Answer (score 2):

As Ben said, the if statements adding 1 if there is a duplicate isn't working. First, each if statement needs to check all of the variables from before, to ensure there are no overlaps.
ex. the if statement in the "m" loop would be as follows:

```
if(m==l || m==k || m==j || m==i){
    m++;
}
```

However this would only fix the problem if there were no consecutive numbers, like k=1, j=2. You'll need to use a while loop to fix this, making your statements as follows:

```
while(m==l || m==k || m==j || m==i){
    m++;
}
```

All together, to list all of the possibilities, your program would be
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
void main()
{
    ofstream out_stream;
    out_stream.open("powerball.txt"); // text file
    for(int i=1; i<=59; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=59; j++){
            while(j==i){
                j++;
            }
            if(j>59) break;
            for(int k=1; k<=59; k++){
                while(k==j || k==i){
                    k++;
                }
                if(k>59) break;
                for(int l=1; l<=59; l++){
                    while(l==k || l==j || l==i){
                        l++;
                    }
                    if(l>59) break;
                    for(int m=1; m<=59; m++){
                        while(m==l || m==k || m==j || m==i){
                            m++;
                        }
                        if(m>59) break;
                        for (int n = 1; n <= 35; n++) // red ball and output count
                            {
                                out_stream << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << " " << m << "\t" << n << "\n";
                                cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << " " << m << "\t" << n << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A better solution, depending on your needs, would be to randomly select the 5 numbers once, unless you need to list all of them.

---

EDIT:
Make sure you have enough disk space to run this, it'll generate an ~352GB file full of numbers.

Comment: Or you could just use `continue` when same number appears instead of increment, then you won't need whole bunch of `if (m > 59) break` lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

with open('powerball.txt', 'w') as f:

    # Generate combinations from 1 to 69
    balls = range(1, 70)
    for combo in itertools.combinations(balls, 5):
        white_balls = list(combo)

        # Add red ball from 1 to 26
        for red_ball in range(1, 27):
            line = str(white_balls+[red_ball])+'\n'
            f.write(line)
            print(line)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).